# Pattern matching cmd command in Net::Telnet

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I am trying to use cmd command from Net::Telnet

```
@lines = $telnet -> cmd(String =>'show run', Prompt => "/patternA/ $/ /patternB/");
```

My intention is to capture something like patternA followed by new line(s) and then followed by pattern B. When i am using above cmd command, its giving bad match operator error.
What is correct way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Lose the double-quotes in the Prompt argument. From the Net::Telnet doco `When constructing the match operator argument for prompt() or waitfor(), always use single quotes instead of double quotes to avoid unexpected backslash interpretation (e.g. '/bash\$ $/')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-prompt` inside `cmd` just be a single pattern.

You can try creating a multiline pattern, but I can't confirm if that will work:

```
@lines = $telnet->cmd(String => 'show run', Prompt => '/patternA\npatternB $/');
```

Also, as stated in [`Net::Telnet #What To Know Before Using`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aTelnet#What-To-Know-Before-Using)

> When constructing the match operator argument for `prompt()` or `waitfor()`, always use single quotes instead of double quotes to avoid unexpected backslash interpretation (e.g. `'/bash\$ $/'`)